# I am trying to create stripe token by other card but it showing You must provide a Stripe Element or a valid token type to create a Token

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using javascript stripe v3 version. i am getting this error
Uncaught IntegrationError: You must provide a Stripe Element or a valid token type to create a Token

1. Case 1 : When there is no payment method added to customer stripe
   element create  create token ,create payment method correctly. after
   that i assigned that payment method to that customer in the backed.

   Case 2: once i had added payment method to customer. and then i try
   to create token ,payment method it show the error "Uncaught
   IntegrationError: You must provide a Stripe Element or a valid token
   type to create a Token" .

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHFBE.png)

[Network error it showing old card detail. however this page does not know about the customer id created in backend or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlJHn.png)

```
<script>
            
    var paymentform = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var subscriptionform = document.getElementById('subscription-form');
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TmlUWbmrA8spLRy5WM1Yq32N');
    // Create an instance of Elements.
    var elements = stripe.elements();
   
    var style = {
    base: {
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        fontSize: '16px',
        '::placeholder': {
        color: '#aab7c4'
        }
    },
    invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };
    var card = elements.create('card');
    card.mount('#card-element');
    // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
    console.log(card);
    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        console.log('triee');
        var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
            displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            displayError.textContent = '';
            stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: card,
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                paymentmethod= result.paymentMethod;
                
                $('#payment_method').val(paymentmethod.id)
            });
            stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                } else {
                    token = result.token;
                    $('#card_token').val(token.id)
                }
                });
                
                
        }
    });
</script>
```

Html Code

```
<form id="payment-form">
<div id="credit_card_form"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="card-element" class="w-100">Card</label>
    <div id="card-element"></div>
    <div id="card-errors"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="clientname"id="clientname"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="card_token"id="card_token"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" id="payment_method"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="payment_type" id="payment_type"/>     
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="button" id="Pay" class="font-size-17 px-5 btn-sm btn-primary">Pay </button>  
</div>
```

Server side code PHP

```
public function attachPaymentMethod(string $paymentMethod, string $customerId)
{
    try {
        $response = $this->client->paymentMethods->attach(
            $paymentMethod,
            ['customer' => $customerId],
        );
        return $response->data;
    } catch (ApiErrorException $e) {
        throw new PaymentServiceException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code that's throwing this error?  It sounds like your reference to the Stripe Card Element isn't working for some reason, but without seeing the code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @JustinMichael code has been placed

Comment: Why are you calling both `stripe.createPaymentMethod` and `stripe.createToken`?  You should only need one or other other (preferably the Payment Method as Tokens are deprecated).

Comment: @JustinMichael but its working for case 1, same is not working for case 2. if i delete old payment method it worked. don't know why it take old card value in card element as you see the second screenshot.

Comment: @JustinMichael did you get a chance to look this issue

Comment: To clarify, if you have only `stripe.createPaymentMethod` and not `stripe.createToken` it works or it doesn't work?  What about the opposite (only `stripe.createToken` and not `stripe.createPaymentMethod`)?

Comment: @JustinMichael i tried both method tried individual but it sending old card detail. not the new one.

Comment: If you remove the `stripe.createToken` part you should be getting a Payment Method inside the value of your `#payment_method` element.  You're not seeing that?  If not can you share more of your code in your question, including the `#payment_method` element and the server-side code that handles the Payment Method?

Comment: @JustinMichael i had added all the code for the above one. as i don't think server code is related to this issue. becuase in server we just use paymentmethodId, which is return by this form.

Comment: So is this working now, or are you still blocked?  If you're still blocked, can you explain exactly what's blocking you in detail?

Comment: @JustinMichael no its not working i am doing it from backend. will send card detail to backend and  do the all process inside the backend.